# Есть такая техника конструирования из бумаги "квиллинг"

Tags: грамотная-речь

Мне вот интересно, склоняется ли слово "квиллинг" или нет?

Comment: @Kalaleva, Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (нажмите на галку рядом с выбранным ответом).

Answer (score 2):

дополнение склоняется, определение нет:

создание изделия с помощью (чего?)  квиллинга;

начальные уроки по (чему?)квиллингу;

цветок в технике (какой?)квиллинг.

Answer (score 1):

Должно склоняться (квиллинг, квиллинга, квиллингу, квиллинг, квиллингом, о квиллинге).